# Open Layers - how find vector

Tags: openlayers

Today I have problem with find vector layer on map. On the map iI have about 1510 diffrent vector in i can doing search box, but i don't know how.

I think i must using `getFeatureById(STRING) - return object` and what now ? Do U have some example code how find vector and for exmaple show popup ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you deal with your DOM. If you use framworks like ExtJS or jQuery you should use the given interface functions to provide a safe and correct way of handling your objects.

But within your application code you can build a function like this:

```
var myMap = new OpenLayers.Map("map1");
var vlayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("VectorLayer");

myMap.addLayer(vlayer);

// add some vectors to your layer...
// ...

// using firebug to show all vectors on the layer
console.log(vlayer.features);

// you can also iterate over all vectors
for (var i = 0; i < vlayer.features.length; ++i) {
  // you could also check if the WKT matches a given string or something else
  console.log(vlayer.features[i]);
}
```

Hope that helps!